# How keep a Secure Value from showing up in Paw's server response panel

Tags: paw-app

I have a parameter stored as a Secure Value and I need to send it as part of the body in a post request.

Even though the parameter is not visible in the left hand request section of Paw, after I execute the request, I can see the parameter value show up un-encrypted in plain text on the right hand side response side in the Request.

Am I missing something? It would be great to have the value be encrypted (*** Hidden Credential ***) all the way through on the UI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you're absolutely right about the credentials on the right hand side not being obfuscated to the user, all request/response pair (aka. HTTP exchange) that are stored by Paw are always encrypted on your disk using the default encryption key you can pick from the File menu > Encryption. Encryption keys are safely stored in your OS X Keychain. Read more here about [encryption in Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/security).

Though, thanks a lot for pointing out this weakness. It's not an easy problem: as soon as the request (left hand editor) is sent, it's serialized to a raw HTTP request (which is then encrypted). In order to obfuscate the credentials on display, we will need to keep track of where the credentials are in this string. We will surely do it in a future version!

Also, please note that APIs/servers may return credentials or other confidential informations that will be shown on the response. This for us would be really hard to detect, as it isn't a data we have generated.